Look a like plants to squash and carrots
We’ve had a random squash looking( at first) plant that has popped up all around and inside our growing beds. We realized it was not our squash when it has grown to about 4-5 ft tall and the leaves are not the awe inspiring size of squash. However it is now flowering the same color as squash. It does not have vines and just one stem. We’ve had a lot of random unidentified plants pop up in our gardens that resemble others such as what looks like carrot tops. They have not flowers yet but are growing more as a single plant leaves have minor difference but I couldn’t tell until I searched images. At this point they are far taller than carrot leaves and magically made it into a bed. We’ve had wild pansies and all sorts of things come up in the yard which I took advantage of and used the around the mailbox. We aren’t sure what these two plants are and would like to know if they are invasive , hazardous, a happy find and edible or tincture worthy etc.
In all cases both plants have popped up next to plants that’s need lots of energy like the garden bed using the three sisters method using squash , corn and green beans. Two sisters the corn and green beans have been wildly successful so we mistook the squash looking plant for the squash that was intended to be there. Carrot looking plants in wildly successful tomato beds etc which is a big clue we didn’t plant it as we did plant carrots direct sow. This is our first time with carrots so again we didn’t catch it. The tall carrot top look alike is in two indeterminate type tomatoes so this plant is robbing nutrients
As the plant is fruiting right now. There’s another squash look a like no where near the bed that is next to Brussel sprout plant on it second year up against the back of the house and one on the side crowding a tomato. The wild carrot topped plant is taking full advantage of the tomato bed also on the side and front of the house. So we aren’t sure why they are obviously taking advantage of being around these high yielding successful plants. Even if it’s a weed since the plants are abundant could this be a weed that isn’t a bad thing and is a companion type plant or is it something edible that the elves and garden gnomes tried to help us out with ? :)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Pictures please

Carrot looks like parsley, airy and not 5' high. Without copy & paste of your picture, it's hard to help.

And paragraphs, please.
